# Minimal Superset that Preserves Derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-topology

I've been playing with some ideas adjacent to vector calculus and have stumbled on to a question which I'm not sure how to approach.

**Question:**

Suppose we have some subset $S\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ and some differentiable function $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$. Is there a domain restriction of $f$ that maintains $f$'s differentiability at points on $S$, but which only includes inputs which are in some sense "arbitrarily close" to $S$?

**Attempts:**

My first thought is to restrict $f$ to $\bigcap N(S)$, the intersection of all neighborhoods of $S$. My reasoning was that each neighborhood preserves the derivatives of $f$ on $S$, and so intersecting them all might give another neighborhood of $S$ that also preserves derivatives. This doesn't work though, because we can let $S=\{x\}$, which has $\bigcap N\big(\{x\}\big) = \{x\}$, but of course $f|_{\{x\}}$'s derivatives don't exist.

Alternatively, perhaps I could just keep $f$ entirely intact and somehow pair it with $S$, but that would need to be handled differently from a normal function, and would require new notations and other grossness.

Past these thoughts, I'm not sure where to go. Any input is welcome!

Comment: What you can do is to consider $N_\varepsilon(S)$ for some fixed but arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: $\bigcup N(S) = S$. Each of the individual neighborhood of $S$ is a bigger set, but for any point $x$ not in $S$, there is at least one neighborhood of $S$ that does not contain $x$. Thus the intersection of all neighborhoods will include the elements of $S$ itself. So your definition accomplishes nothing.

Comment: Usually in cases like this, you define $f : \Omega \to \Bbb R$ for some open domain $\Omega \subset \Bbb R^2$ with $S \subset \Omega$. Thus you are guaranteed that $f'$ is definable at every point of $S$. But $\Omega$ is otherwise restrictable to be as small a neighborhood as you may need.

Comment: I trust it isn't necessary to explain, but for completeness, I meant $\bigcap N(S) = S$ in my first comment (far too late to fix it now).

Comment: @PaulSinclair thanks for the nice little proof that $\bigcap N(S) = S$, I think that nicely shows why a simple restriction can't work. If you put an answer with that, I'd accept it. Also, I've read since that neighborhood filters may be what I'm looking for. Do you how those could be applied here?

Comment: You seem to be set on making this far more complicated than it needs to be. You need $f$ to have a well-defined derivative (holding in all directions) at each point of $S$, so you have to have $f$ defined on some neighborhood of every point of $S$. That means $f$ has to be defined on some open set $\Omega$ that contains $S$. That $\Omega$ can be taken at any size, no matter how small, about $S$, but in the end there si no way to restrict a fixed function $f$ any farther without losing the necessary property. Fixed functions are not defined on filters. They are defined on fixed sets.